# ComplexWarning with scipy.linalg.eig or eigvals

Tags: python, scipy, eigenvalue

I'm trying to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem in Python, so I'm using [`scipy.linalg.eigvals`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigvals.html) for this purpose. Specifically, I call

```
scipy.linalg.eigvals(A, B)
```

where `A` and `B` are 2 arrays of the same shape containing complex numbers.

When I do this, I get the following warning:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp.py:57: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part

overwrite_a, overwrite_b)
```

And it doesn't yield the expected eigenvalues. This also happens if I set `B` to have real values while keeping `A` complex, and the other way around. The warning doesn't show only if both arrays contain only `floats`.

It also happens when I use `eig` instead of `eigvals`.

However, according to the [scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigvals.html), the arrays can be complex:

Any idea why this warning pops up? I would be glad if someone could explain what is happening. Thanks!

*EDIT*: I just checked my scipy version, and it's the [0.9.0 version](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.9.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigvals.html#scipy.linalg.eigvals). However, I'm not working on my own PC, so I'd rather not bother the tech staff to update unless the issue comes from here.

*EDIT*: It turns out that the eigenvalues are actually right, even though the warning happens. As Warren Weckesser pointed out, the warning doesn't happen with scipy ver 0.10.0 and above.

Comment: Is your `B` invertible? I don't get the warning when I use the function in single-matrix mode (`eigvals(dot(A, inv(B)))`). I also get the correct eigenvalues even when I get the warning though; can you provide an example where you get the wrong eigenvalues?

Comment: There was a change in version 0.10.0 that avoids an unnecessary ComplexWarning: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/1f38096ec40fdc4c188b0f5f73f39c9223f1d1ef.  However, that wouldn't explain why the values that you get are not what you expect.  Can you add the arrays to the question along with the result that you get?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for pointing out that the eigenvalues should still be correct. After playing with some more test cases, I noticed that indeed they are correct (even with the warning), and that it was the analytic solution I was comparing them to that was off.